# Determine navigation events using adb, when activity is replaced in the stack

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to determine what navigation event took place after a click event?

I have tried using the android back stack, retrieving them using the following commands:

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows 
adb shell dumpsys activity top
```

It’s obvious that if stack size increases, there was a forward navigation and if it decreases, there was backward navigation.

But what about when the top activity in the stack was replaced? Are there any directional navigation events that can be grabbed via adb?